# Lookup Method in MongoDb using Linq returning empty array

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have two collections namely "Notification" and "NotificationData" in the same database in MongoDb. I am trying to join two collections and retrive the required information from the two collections.

```
 var query = notificationDataCollection.AsQueryable().Join(
                notificationCollection.AsQueryable(),
                p => p.Id,
                q => q.NotificationDataId,
                (p, q) => new
                {
                    ActorId = p.ActorId
                });
```

The driver has tranformed the results like this:

```
{aggregate([{ "$lookup" : { "from" : "Notification", "localField" : "_id", "foreignField" : "NotificationDataId", "as" : "q" } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$q" }, 
{ "$project" : { "ActorId" : "$ActorId", "_id" : 0 } }])}
```

I am getting an empty Array eventhough there is a record matching the given criteria

For example: the Data in Mongo is stored

Notification

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e6b9564aece6902bcb0cd20"},
"NotificationDataId":"5e6b9563aece6902bcb0cd1f",
"NotifierId":"175ff977-c62a-45f4-9539-eb916c52db52",
"NotifierName":null,
"Status":{"$numberInt":"1"}}
```

NotificationData

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e6b9563aece6902bcb0cd1f"},
"Entity":{"_t":"ProductQuoteRequest","UserId":null,"BuyerId":"eb30dfce-a2a3-49ef-8f86-eda48c636f1b",
"SellerId":"175ff977-c62a-45f4-9539-eb916c52db52",
"Subject":"string","Message":"Hey"},
"EntityType":"TraderZ.ProductQuoteRequest",
"ActorId":"eb30dfce-a2a3-49ef-8f86-eda48c636f1b",
"CreatedOn":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1584108899661"}},
"Status":{"$numberInt":"1"}}
```

Comment: Note that string != objectId. It looks like your _id fields are ObjectId but your NotificationDataId field is string.

Comment: I did try to convert by p.Id.ToString() but it throws the following exception  unable to determine the serialization information for the outer key selector in the tree: aggregate([]).Join(aggregate([]), p => p.Id.ToString(), q => q.NotificationDataId, (p, q) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(Name = p.ActorId))

Comment: You might want to try `(string)p.Id`, although I've never done anything like this. A better solution would definitely be to fix your database so the types match.

Comment: I tried like that . As of now it is not throwing an exception but the results are still returning an empty array

Comment: @John I converted the type of NotificationDataId from string to ObjectId and now it works.